# Vue.js navigation guards, block every auth route, allow login to required routes when user provides correct information

Tags: javascript, spring, vue.js, vuex, vue-router

I'm trying to create a navigation guard in vuejs with the following logic: Block all requiredAuth routes and redirect to login when the user isn't authenticated, except for the login route to allow the user to sign in and it doesn't hang (loop) (this is the part I'm stuck on). When the user is authenticated and tries to access a restricted route, or non restricted route when authenticated, allow access.

So basically I want to allow user to non restricted routes, allow sign in, and block access to restricted routes when not authenticated.

If I'm not making sense regarding my logic, please correct me as I've been stuck on this for a while and may need someone else's perspective.

Here's the code.

The code is mainly from a tutorial I followed on bezkoder.com, then I took a course on Vue on Udemy by Maximilian Schwarzmuller and he introduced me to navigation guards. This is my first time using them so please bear with me.

main.js

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import router from './router/index.js';
import App from './App.vue'
import TheNav from './components/TheNav.vue'
import  { store } from './store/index.js';
import VueParticles from 'vue-particles';

var app = createApp(App);

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if(to.path !== '/login' && to.meta.requiredAuth && !store.getters.isAuthenticated){
        next('/login');
        return
    } else if (from.path === '/login' && to.meta.requiredAuth && store.getters.isAuthenticated){
        next();
        return
    } else if (!to.meta.requiredAuth && store.getters.isAuthenticated){
        next();
        return
    } else if (to.meta.requiredAuth && store.getters.isAuthenticated){
        next();
        return
    } else {
        next();
    }
})

app.use(router);
app.use(store);
  

app.config.productionTip = false;
  
app.component('app-nav', TheNav);

app.use(VueParticles);

app.mount('#app');
```

auth.module.js The auth module is exported in the store/index.js. So it's the store.

```
import AuthService from '../services/auth.service';

const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
const initialState = user
  ? { status: { loggedIn: true }, user }
  : { status: { loggedIn: false }, user: null };

export const auth = {
  namespaced: true,
  state: initialState,
  actions: {
    login({ commit }, user) {
      return AuthService.login(user).then(
        user => {
          commit('loginSuccess', user);
          return Promise.resolve(user);
        },
        error => {
          commit('loginFailure');
          return Promise.reject(error);
        }
      );
    },
    logout({ commit }) {
      AuthService.logout();
      commit('logout');
    },
    register({ commit }, user) {
      return AuthService.register(user).then(
        response => {
          commit('registerSuccess');
          return Promise.resolve(response.data);
        },
        error => {
          commit('registerFailure');
          return Promise.reject(error);
        }
      );
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    loginSuccess(state, user) {
      state.status.loggedIn = true;
      state.user = user;
    },
    loginFailure(state) {
      state.status.loggedIn = false;
      state.user = null;
    },
    logout(state) {
      state.status.loggedIn = false;
      state.user = null;
    },
    registerSuccess(state) {
      state.status.loggedIn = false;
    },
    registerFailure(state) {
      state.status.loggedIn = false;
    }
  },
  getters: {
    isAuthenticated(state){
      return state.status.loggedIn;
    }
  }
};
```

Here's the full project. I can't post all the code as it would be too much for here.
**https://github.com/mupml/PeopleZone-Spring-Security-Spring-Boot-Vue.js**

As I've mentioned, my approach could be fundamentally flawed.

Spring backend, if necessary but I don't believe this is the problem. I hope not anyway. MySQL DB.

**https://github.com/mupml/person-search-spring-boot-vue-security**

The problem I'm experiencing is it blocks the restricted routes fine, but when I try login, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: When I said previously that it was blocking the restricted routes fine, I was wrong, it just wasn't showing anything and wasn't redirecting to login as specified.

Comment: I have provided here a workaround with Best Practises: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65588580/how-to-change-component-rendered-by-router-on-state-change-in-vue/65598734#65598734

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. A bit of debugging using console.log in the before each done the trick. The getters method I was accessing via the store was showing as undefined and as such, none of the conditions in the before each were being met. Here's the code I have now and it seems to be working. I changed the getter from isAuthenticated, to access the store state directly. I know the getters is better practise but it wasn't working. Maybe it was because it was in the main.js and not in a Vue component.

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    console.log(store.state.auth.status.loggedIn);
    if(to.path != '/login' && to.meta.requiredAuth && !store.state.auth.status.loggedIn){
        next('/login');
    } else if (from.path == '/login' && to.meta.requiredAuth && store.state.auth.status.loggedIn){
        console.log('this hit')
        next();
    } else {
        next();
    }
})
```